# How to maintain data consistency in for update operation in nosql?

Tags: mongodb, database

For example, we have a table like below

```
car_id, car_name, car_status, engine
100,    car1,     running,    A
200，   car2,     stop,       B
```

The business logic is engine can not be updated while car_status is running

The most obvious step is

1. Check if status is running,
2. Update if status is not running

The problem is that someone may change the status to running during the time between step 1 and 2.

How do you to prevent this in RDBMS and mongo?

Comment: What do you mean by *RDBMS and mongo*? Are you asking about mongo? Or about relational database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep only a single way to update your car_status in your application and expose that function as the sole way to update car_status( you can create a user in the database which has write rights for this table or collection and this will force you to always use only that user_id to run this update operation and ofcourse this would apply when doing from application as well.)